# How to access and edit the attributes of the controls inside an iframe through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, .net, iframe

I need to access a button inside an iframe through javascript. Below is the iframe code in the aspx file:

```
<iframe id="headerframe" runat="server" src="./DashHeader.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" style="width:inherit;height:inherit;overflow:hidden;">
            </iframe>
```

There is a tab strip in the same file:

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadTabStrip1" Orientation="HorizontalTop" Width="100%" Height="32px" OnClientTabSelected="tabClicked" OnClientTabSelecting="savePreviousTab" SelectedIndex="0" >
                </telerik:RadTabStrip>
```

When I try to access the control btnSearch(which belongs to the iframe) from the tabClick method of the tabstrip, I am able to find the button and perform the required action.

```
function tabClicked(sender, args) {
                    document.getElementById('headerframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('btnSearch').style = "something";                                                     
                }
```

But when I try to access the same control from a different custom javascript function, I am not able to access the required control.

```
function setSearchButtonVisibility()
                {
                    document.getElementById('headerframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('btnSearch').style = "something";
                }
```

Please suggest what needs to be done in this case.

Comment: Where are `tabClicked` and `setSearchButtonVisibility` called?

Comment: @iamdlm, tabClicked is called from the onClientTabSelected event of the tab strip, and setSearchButtonVisibility is something that is being called from code behind using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript.